# Can the Stack Exchange navigation images be moved in a separate sprite from the social icons?

Tags: feature-request, design

I had this strange issue: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/70080 and traced it back to AdBlock Plus blocking the toolbar sprite which contains both the social icons (Facebook, Twitter...) and the toolbar icons.

Is there a reason for grouping these together? Can the navigation/toolbar icons be moved to a separate sprite?

Comment: Why do they need separated? They could just as easily rename the file, and then they're not adding an extra HTTP request.

Comment: I doubt they'll separate them just so you can ad-block only part of the site; ad-blockers are not a supported feature.

Comment: I believe things should be grouped when it makes sense, otherwise why not have a single sprite image? Are social icons really a part of navigation (intended design) or were they put there by chance (and nobody considered changing it)?

Comment: They're grouped like that because those are all the images that **every single site on the network** uses. Always the same icons, wherever you go. The sprite with the logos and such is separated because those images change on each site you visit.